# Moving Fallout NV game saves between PS3s?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm at someone else's house for a week, and wanted to load my Fallout New Vegas saves on their PS3. I brought a few saves on a USB stick which I've copied with the 'Save Game Utility'.

When I load the savefile in Fallout NV, I get:

> 'Warning: You are loading a save game that belongs to another user. You will be unable to save your progress or unlock trophies.'

Couldn't care less about the trophies, but I do need to save progress!

Anyone have suggestions? I am not averse to a bit of savefile editing if that helps, but not sure where I'd find instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new local user on the other PS3 (the far-left menu item on the XMB), and then sign in to your PSN account while using that local user. The PS3 would thus need to be connected to the internet. Your PSN account can be linked to 5 different PS3 machines.

Sony now have a feature where your save files are backed up to "the cloud", and automatically downloaded to all PS3s connected to your PSN account. Sounds like that could be useful for you, however you would need to pay for Playstation Plus membership to use it.

Comment: Doh, that seems obvious! Thanks for helping me out.